# Light bulb connection to the ceiling

Tags: electrical

I wish to connect a light bulb connection (2 wire connection) to the ceiling but there are 3 wires:

1) Yellow/Green, 2) Blue, 3)Black

I live in Germany, which two wires do I connect ?

Comment: I believe in Germany yellow/green is ground/earth, blue is neutral, and black is hot (but I could be wrong, as I don't live there).

Comment: Hello, yes I checked the colours in a table and you are correct regarding the colours, also in Germany but which two wires should I connect ? I wish to live a long and happy life ?

Comment: If the fixture does not have an earth connection just use blue for the neutral and brown for the live. What colors are at the fixture?

Comment: What type of fitting is it? For some, it doesn't matter. Only exception is screw bulbs, where the centre connection should be phase.

Answer (score 1):

Who knows?  Europe is in the middle of  harmonizing their wiring standards.  There's a lot of old and new work out there.

In one of several old standards, black is neutral.  The new standard is blue for neutral.  What you know for sure is that green is ground.  The other two are hot and neutral.  If your lamp doesn't care, that may be enough.

If it does care, measure voltage between one of the wires and ground.   The hot will be around 230V to ground.  The neutral will be 0-2 volts.